# Build error using MaterialDrawer Library

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying this [MaterialDrawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) But I am encountering a build error during setup.  Has anyone used this library and knows what could be causing this issue? I already opened an issue on their github page but since Stackoverflow has millions of programmers I am wondering if any of you have used this library before and knows how to resolve this?

This has only one dependency

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.5.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Below is the error:

```
C:\Dev\AndroidWorkspace\NotBoringActionBar-master\App\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Dev\AndroidWorkspace\NotBoringActionBar-master\App\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-ldrtl-v23\values-ldrtl-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Dev\AndroidWorkspace\NotBoringActionBar-master\App\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.mikepenz\materialize\0.5.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:statusBarColor'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds'.
```

**UPDATE BUILD GRADLE**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           // runProguard true
           // proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


}
```

Comment: You may want to consider the official Google NavigationView  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

Answer (score 0):

The **MaterialDrawer** uses the support libraries **v23.1.1** those require to be built with the `compileSdkVersion 23`

Update your gradle to:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

and also update the used support library to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

If you can't do this for some reason. (You definitely always should choose to use the latest support libraries) you may exclude the support libraries from the `MaterialDrawer`, but I excpect this to create many strange issues. Even v1.0.0 of the `MaterialDrawer` used the support libs v21.x