# How to use MaterialDrawer step by step?

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I am searching for step by step tutorial on using MaterialDrawer (https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer.git) library. Can I found jar file of this?

I have searched many times but couldn't find any help. All I found is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937207/build-error-using-materialdrawer-library). But there is not any answer.

Comment: Please stop with the rollbacks. If this is an attempt to "bump" your question, it's not working, and I've locked the post to get this to halt.

Comment: Follow this link: https://hemantvc.blogspot.com/2015/07/materialdrawer.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in your grade file:

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.4@aar') {
transitive = true
}
```

It's clearly mentioned on the library's page.

To add the drawer to your activity use:

```
new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
```

The library has documentation regarding how to set up the drawer, how to add items, just take a look at it and try it in your app.

Comment: yeah I have added that. then what next? where to add drawer?

Comment: Thanks. If I encounter any problem later I'll tell.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, and all you need has been present in documentation.

Step 1: Open build.gradle in 'app' folder, add following line to dependencies:

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.4@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Step 2: Add following line to onCreate method:

```
new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
```

Read more in documentation to know how to custom your drawer!